# Why margins don't work in Internet Explorer with html5 & overflow:hidden?

Tags: html, css

HTML:

```
<main>
  <p>
  this is a paragraph in main...
  </p>
</main>
<section>
  this is a section...
</section>
```

CSS:

```
p{ margin:100px; background:#99ff99; }
main{ overflow:hidden; background:#ff9999; }
section{ margin:100px; background:#9999ff; }
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fhbyw80m/

**Also why margin don't work in IE when we use like this?**

HTML:

```
<main>
  <p>
  this is a paragraph...
  </p>
</main>
<aside>
  this is aside...
</aside>
```

CSS:

```
main{background:#ff9999; margin-bottom:150px; }
p{background:#99ff99; margin-bottom:30px; }
aside{background:#9999ff;}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gLLt9vhy/

Comment: It seems a bug, they fixed it for Edge.

Comment: @Oriol if it is a bug then why they are not fixing IE first ???

Comment: @Oriol, I don't believe it is a bug. It's just that `main` isn't defined in IE's default style sheet, so the element uses CSS initial values ([per the spec](https://drafts.csswg.org/css2/cascade.html#specified-value)). Thus, `display: inline` gets applied and `margin` and `overflow` don't work as expected.

Comment: @Michael_B True, and I considered deleting the comment after seeing your answer. But I think when IE 11 was published, `main` had already been standardized (or it was clear it would become standardized). Then, not displaying it as a block in the default stylesheet could be considered a bug :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `main` element is not supported by Internet Explorer.

See browser compatibility at http://caniuse.com/#search=Main.

Also see:

- [<main> element not working in Internet Explorer 11](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35820429/3597276)
- [Default settings of unrecognized HTML elements](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35689456/3597276)

Comment: then what should I do if I want to make a website on html5 and also want to tell search engines about my main content with <main> ?

Comment: i am using IE11, it still have partial support...

Comment: you are right... when i replaced <main> with <div> in both fiddles then margins are working, so should i use div for main wrapper still in html5 just because IE11 don't support it ?

Comment: @BlackFire - just add `main { display:block; }` and IE11 is fine.

Comment: @Alohci Thank you very much! But why this? because it's partially supported by IE11? so should i also use display:block; for other partially supported elements?

Comment: Unrecognised elements take the initial values of CSS properties. For `display` that's `inline`. Because `<main>` is (relatively) new, IE11 doesn't recognise it, so treats it as an inline element. Top and bottom margins have no effect on non-replaced inline elements, and `overflow:hidden` only creates a block fomatting context on block boxes, not inline ones, hence the effects you see.