# Default settings of unrecognized HTML elements

Tags: css, html, language-lawyer, w3c

If I use custom or unsupported elements in my HTML they can still be styled and the browser will render them.

For instance, the HTML5 `main` element is not supported by Internet Explorer 11 and older ([source](http://caniuse.com/#search=main)). When `main` is rendered by IE, CSS rules involving `margin` and `overflow` are ignored. This implies that the `display` value of an unrecognized element is `inline`.

Where are the initial settings for an unrecognized element defined?

(NOTE: I'm not asking about the pros and cons of using custom elements. I just want to know what CSS does by default.)

Comment: If it's unrecognised...how can it have default properties? You have to check the spec. I'd suggest it's browser specific. = https://www.w3.org/TR/custom-elements/

Comment: Thanks, @Paulie_D. I'm under the impression that CSS has rules for processing unrecognized elements (see the [comments in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35688664/3597276)). The rule may just be to take the initial value of a CSS property. I'm trying to find where in the spec the handling is defined, but my searches have yielded no results.

Comment: What I'm thinking is that they **aren't** defined...because the developer is supposed to define them...so it's arbitrary as to what each browser does.

Comment: All sort of interesting stuff here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20353613/why-does-css-work-with-fake-elements

Comment: ..especially this - https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110405/infrastructure.html#other-applicable-specifications

Comment: ...and a comment from @Boltclock *"As far as CSS is concerned, if there is no browser default display value it uses the **initial** value. "* - my emphasis

Comment: ...and this http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/customelements/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not so much *unrecognized* elements, as *all* elements. Remember that CSS supports XML as well as HTML. In XML, all elements are *unrecognized*

In the CSS 2.1 spec, [section 6.1.1](https://drafts.csswg.org/css2/cascade.html#specified-value) says:

> 6.1.1 Specified values
>
> User agents must first assign a specified value to each property based
> on the following mechanisms (in order of precedence):
>
> 1. If the cascade results in a value, use it. Except that, if the value is 'inherit', the specified value is defined in “The 'inherit'
>    value” below.
> 2. Otherwise, if the property is inherited and the element is not the root of the document tree, use the computed value of the parent
>    element.
> 3. Otherwise use the property's initial value. The initial value of each property is indicated in the property's definition.

By definition, unrecognized elements won't be mentioned in the user agent style sheet, and since we're talking about the default behaviour, won't be mentioned in the author style sheet either. So 1 does not apply.

The display property is defined in [9.2.4 The 'display' property](https://drafts.csswg.org/css2/visuren.html#propdef-display). In the rules there, it says `Inherited: no`, so 2 does not apply.

So 3 applies. Again from the rules at 9.2.4, we have `Initial: inline`, so the elements are inline.

For HTML block level elements, they are block by default simply because they are listed as such in the user-agent's style sheet. Similarly for other display values such as `table`, `list-item` etc.

Comment: Just to be clear: Were it not for the user agent stylesheets, all elements would be `display: inline` by default? All elements would use the initial values of CSS properties?

Comment: @Michael_B - That's correct. More or less anyway: There are a few things in HTML that can't be replicated directly in CSS. Form elements, for example, and rowspan & colspan in tables. So occasionally, browsers do treat some HTML elements as "magic".

Comment: @Michael_B: Yes - this is why the concept of an initial value exists.

Comment: @BoltClock, interesting to note: Not all CSS properties have an initial value (ex. [***font-family***](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/fonts.html#propdef-font-family) and [***color***](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/colors.html#colors)).

Comment: @Michael_B: Yep, some of these are determined by the browser, and in many cases can be configured via user preferences.