# <main> element not working in Internet Explorer 11

Tags: css, html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

I'm trying to set the width of a `<main>` element with CSS. Just using

```
main {
  width:200px;
}
```

works fine in all browsers except Internet Explorer (Edge does work).

Take a look at this example: [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1x9hbb4p/1/)

The result in IE11:

[image]

The result in Chrome:

[image]

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The HTML5 `main` element is not supported by Internet Explorer ([see browser support data](http://caniuse.com/#search=main)).

You'll need to define `main` as a block-level element for `width` to work.

Make this adjustment:

```
main {
  display: block;  /* new */
  width: 200px;
}
```

Because the `main` element is not recognized by Internet Explorer – meaning it's not defined in IE's default style sheet – it uses CSS initial values ([per the spec](https://drafts.csswg.org/css2/cascade.html#specified-value)).

The initial value of the [`display`](https://drafts.csswg.org/css2/visuren.html#propdef-display) property is `inline`.

The `width` property is ignored by inline elements. From the spec:

> [**10.3.1 Inline, non-replaced
>   elements**](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-CSS2/visudet.html#q4)
>
> The `width` property does not apply.

By defining the `main` element as a block-level element in author styles, the `width` property will work.

More details:

- [Default settings of unrecognized HTML elements](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35689456/3597276)
- [Default style sheet for HTML 4](https://drafts.csswg.org/css2/sample.html)
- [`main` property browser compatibility](http://caniuse.com/#search=main)
- [`display` property definition and initial value](https://drafts.csswg.org/css2/visuren.html#propdef-display)

Comment: Thanks, this works! Weird that IE11 doesn't support this simple HTML5 tag.

Comment: @JensRenders It takes IE years to support new elements, CSS properties and APIs that all other browsers support so, no, this is no surprise and won't be much different in Edge.

Comment: The main tag is display: block by default in Edge :)